# How to filter users in Active Directory for InActive Users in .Net?

Tags: .net, active-directory

I want to create a filter to fetch all the Active users in Active directory, I used this filter but it didn't worked

```
searcher.Filter = string.Format(
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
                "(&(|(samaccountname={0})(mailnickname={0}))(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))",
                alias);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace.

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// which is not enabled (not active)
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.Enabled = false;

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I wanted to know how to add filter for the condition (|(samaccountname={0})(mailnickname={0})) I can set the property for samaccountname but not for mailnickname. and in my list there are some users with mailnickname as given alias.

Answer (score 0):

Grab adfind from www.joeware.net and you can use it to test filters - `adfind -f "<your filter here>"` -default will do the trick.

What you pasted looks accurate although I would further scope it to users only like this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(|(samaccountname={0})(mailnickname={0}))(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))
```